# Does Java object get created in CPU's cache or it always be RAM

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-memory-model

I'm confused with the fact that read/write to main memory is very costly, so threads do not make a call to main memory frequently and instead try to work in the cache.

Now assume Thread-1 has started and has created an object - say myObject - and then starts a new thread - say Thread-2 - and passes the reference of myObject to it.

Now assume Thread-1 is running in core-1 of CPU, and Thread-2 got another core - say core-2 of CPU. Now my questions are:

1. When Thread-2 will try to access myObject passed to it, since it is not there in cache of core-2, then where exactly Thread-2 will look for myObject(since Thread-2 already got reference(address) of myObject from Thread-1)?
2. Is the address that Thread-1 holds in core-1's memory location or Main memory?
3. Depending on the answer of first 2 questions: does the object always get created in RAM,and not in local cache of core in which the thread is currently working on?

P.S.: Please assume there is no synchronization or volatility in the picture.

Comment: Cache use happens automatically. It's handled by the processor.

Comment: If you're trying to reason about multithreaded program semantics, cache and RAM are not what you should be thinking about. Learn the Java memory model. Think in terms of the Java memory model, not cache and RAM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not something done on the Java level, it's just inherent in how the OS or CPU itself manage RAM usage. If you're using Java, it's not really something you should worry about (in part because Java should try to keep things cache-coherent (I think it does so based on object type?), but also because there's not a lot of control for it given to you).

When you ask for memory, the OS will find some unused RAM to give you, and load the page it's in to the cache (pages are usually 4KB). If you perform any write operations anywhere in the page, it will get flagged as "[dirty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_bit)". Anything you do to objects in that page can be done at the cache level, and will be pretty fast. If another core wants to touch data in that page, it will check its cache and - if the cache isn't shared - cause a cache-miss when it doesn't find it, making it try to load from RAM where it will see the "dirty" bit set, and cause the cached page to save to RAM before loading for the new core to read.

Comment: Thanx for you answer. Could you please give me the answer as per the points mentioned in questions if possible for you. Thanx in adavnce.

Comment: This answer is wrong. There is no automatic cache coherence in Java. In absence of correct thread communication (as the OP stated, “there is no synchronization or volatility”), there is no guaranty that the second thread will read correct data. It might read default values (`null` or zero) instead of initialized fields or if multiple updates were made, the second thread might read arbitrary outdated values, even in mismatched versions (“out of order”). The second paragraph describes a particular hardware architecture, but even there, code optimizations may cause perceiving inconsistent data.